# How can I change text "App would like to use your current location?"

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, cllocationmanager, userlocation

Can we change this text?

I have used property `purpose` of `CLLocationManager` class. But message did not change.

```
[locationManager setPurpose:@"Change text message"];
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a key in your info.plist like: `NSLocationUsageDescription` and add your string as it's value.

**iOS 8 and greater**

They introduced two more keys other than [NSLocationUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW27)

1. [NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW18)
2. [NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW26)

**iOS 6 or greater**

> **NSLocationUsageDescription**
>
> “Privacy - Location Usage Description”
>
> Specifies the reason for accessing the user’s location information.
>   See “NSLocationUsageDescription” for details.
>
> iOS 6.0 and later

Check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html) for reference

**iOS 3.2 to iOS 5**

> **purpose**
>
> An application-provided string that describes the reason for using
>   location services. (Deprecated in iOS 6.0.)
>
> `@property(copy, nonatomic)`
>   `NSString *purpose Discussion`
>
> If this property is not nil and the system needs to ask for the user’s
>   consent to use location services, it displays the provided string. You
>   can use this string to explain why your application is using location
>   services.
>
> **You must set the value of this property prior to starting any location
>   services. Because the string is ultimately displayed to the user, you
>   should always load it from a localized strings file.**
>
> Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
> Deprecated in iOS 6.0.
> ```
>
> Declared In CLLocationManager.h

Comment: Is is legal? Will apple approve?

Comment: @SangamAngre: I found this key from their documentation. So I think they won't reject.

Comment: I am developing app for version 5.1 and later.

Comment: I tried to setup purpose as [locationManager setPurpose:@"Change text message"]; but text message does not change

Comment: Have you read the title of question "How can I change text “App would like to use your current location?”"    He want to change this text, not want to add some text below it.